# Jquery get optgroup label and its childs

Tags: jquery, optgroup

How could it get `box_B` optgroup's label name based on `box_A` option that is selected?

I use following function tried to alert `box_A` parent label but unable to get it, if I changed to `var label = $(e).attr('value');`, the option value is show.

```
function showLabel(e){ 
    if($(e).attr('checked')=='checked'){
         var label = $(e).parent().attr('label');
         alert(label);
    }
}
```

select box:

```
<select id="box_A" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Asia: Japan">
        <option value="1 - Toyota">1 - Toyota</option>
        <option value="2 - Honda">2 - Honda</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Europe: German">
        <option value="3 - Mercedes">3 - Mercedes</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<select id="box_B" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="1 - Toyota">
        <option value="1A - Camry">1A - Camry</option>
        <option value="1B - Yaris">1B - Yaris</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2 - Honda">
        <option value="2A - Civic">2A - Civic</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="3 - Mercedes">
        <option value="3A - SL320">3A - SL320</option>
    </optgroup>

</select>
```

call the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#box_A").multiSelect({}, showLabel);

}
```

thanks.

Comment: Where is `showLabel` being called, and what are you passing as the `e` argument? Also, you are missing the end tag for the `optgroup` element.

Comment: for option there is not attribute `checked` instead use `selected` or selectedIndexof.

Comment: sorry, I missed to include call function, pls see my edited post.

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar, I use jquery-multiselect plugin to randered a checkbox for each options, so `checked` is working.

Comment: @conmen Could you please link the to multiselect plugin you are using in your question? This is important to know when answering the question so we understand how/when `showLabel` is being called, how the plugin works, and what arguments `showLabel` receives.

Comment: @Zhihao, here is jq-multiselect plugin: http://ytjobwebsite.googlecode.com/svn-history/r780/trunk/job/webapp/js/plugin/multiselect/jquery.multiSelect.js

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `showLabel` is called and is passed a jQuery event object when an option is clicked, you could use this:

```
function showLabel(e){ 
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.is(':selected')){
         var label = $target.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
         alert(label);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

After taking a looking at the plugin you posted, it looks like my assumptions above were wrong. `showLabel` is not being passed a jQuery event, but is instead passed the jQuery object for the clicked item, which is also a checkbox and not an option. Try using this instead:

```
function showLabel($target){ 
    if($target.is(':checked')){
         var label = $target.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
         alert(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: @conmen I've updated my answer based on the plugin link you posted. What I was hoping for when asking for a link though was to see any available documentation for the plugin rather than the actual code for it.

Comment: this time the alert poped with value `undefined`

Comment: @conmen Sorry about the late response. It seems that the passed argument, `$target` is not an `optgroup` or a child of one. This may be because the plugin is inserting markup outside of your `select` elements. Do you have an example of this plugin in action or provide a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that I can inspect the markup structure? You can also do this yourself through your browser's developer tools. It is difficult to help you at this point without a working sample or any documentation.